# Count Pattern Matching using Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I've been trying to Count Pattern Matching using Sparklyr.

I'm trying to count the number of time the pattern ";" appears in the variable room_number

Here is mytable :

```
room_number      
A12;A19        
A13            
A15;A14;A20
```

When I don't use Sparklyr I can use this function:

```
count.matches <- function(pat, vec) sapply(regmatches(vec, gregexpr(pat, vec)), length)

mytable <- mytable %>%
mutate(number_pattern = mapply(count.matches, c(';'), list(room_number)))
```

I get:

```
room_number    number_pattern    
A12;A19        1
A13            0
A15;A14;A20    2
```

if I try to apply the code in distributed R with sparklyr using `spark_apply` instead of `mapply`, I get the following message :

```
mytable  <- mytable  %>%
+   mutate(number_pattern = spark_apply(count.matches, c(';'), list(room_number)))
glimpse(mytable)
```

> Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
>     no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "function"

Do you have any tips ? 
Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark_apply` is a standalone function, and cannot be use in `mutate`. Also it doesn't have the same API as `mapply`:

```
count.matches <- function(pat) function(df) {
  f <- function(vec) sapply(regmatches(vec, gregexpr(pat, vec)), length)
  dplyr::mutate(df, number_pattern = f(room_number))
}

mytable %>% spark_apply(count.matches(";"))
```